# Split array struct to single value column Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, explode

I have a dataframe with single array struct column where I want to split the nested values and added as a comma separated string new column(s)
Example dataframe:
tests

```
{id:1,name:foo},{id:2,name:bar}
```

Expected result dataframe

```
tests                            tests_id  tests_name
[id:1,name:foo],[id:2,name:bar]  1, 2     foo, bar
```

I tried the below code but got an error

```
df.withColumn("tests_name", concat_ws(",", explode(col("tests.name"))))
```

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Generators are not supported when it's nested in expressions, but got: concat_ws(,, explode(tests.name AS `name`));
```

Comment: can you share the schema of dataframe, what version of spark are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the Spark version you are using. Assuming the dataframe scheme as below

```
root
 |-- test: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

**Spark 3.0.0**

```
df.withColumn("id", concat_ws(",", transform($"test", x => x.getField("id"))))
  .withColumn("name", concat_ws(",", transform($"test", x => x.getField("name"))))
.show(false)
```

**Spark 2.4.0+**

```
df.withColumn("id", concat_ws(",", expr("transform(test, x -> x.id)")))
.withColumn("name", concat_ws(",", expr("transform(test, x -> x.name)")))
.show(false)
```

**Spark < 2.4**

```
val extract_id = udf((test: Seq[Row]) => test.map(_.getAs[Long]("id")))
val extract_name = udf((test: Seq[Row]) => test.map(_.getAs[String]("name")))

df.withColumn("id", concat_ws(",", extract_id($"test")))
  .withColumn("name", concat_ws(",", extract_name($"test")))
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+---+-------+
|test                |id |name   |
+--------------------+---+-------+
|[[1, foo], [2, bar]]|1,2|foo,bar|
|[[3, foo], [4, bar]]|3,4|foo,bar|
+--------------------+---+-------+
```